# Show that $f(x)=1/\sqrt x$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I have the function $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ if $x\in(0,1]$ and $0$ otherwise. I am trying to show that f is measurable using that f is measurable if $\forall r\in\mathbb{R} $, one has $f^{-1}((-\infty,r))\in\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}).$ Where I mean with $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$ the Borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb{R}$. I know that this is the sigma algebra generated by the open sets in $\mathbb{R}$, but I have diffictulties how I can show that $f^{-1}((-\infty,r))\in\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and how $f^{-1}((-\infty,r))$ is defined. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: If $r$ is non-negative then $f^{-1}((-\infty, r)) = \varnothing$. If $r$ is positive then $f^{-1}((-\infty,r)) = (-\infty,0] \cup (\frac{1}{r^2},\infty)$.

Comment: A modest proposal:  after understanding how this works, prove that a function with only finitely many discontinuities is Borel measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the definition of inverse mapping:
$$f^{-1}((-\infty,r])=\{x\in \mathbb{R}:f(x)\leq r\}=\begin{cases}
\emptyset &r<0\\
(-\infty,0]\cup (1,\infty)& 0\leq r <1\\
(-\infty,0]\cup [1/r^2,\infty)&r\geq 1
\end{cases}$$
all these sets belong to $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\{(-\infty,r],r \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a generator of the Borel sets so $f$ is measurable.

Comment: Thank you! How do you come to the term $(-\infty,0]$? f(x) is not defined for a negative x right?

Comment: @mathastic you wrote '$0$ otherwise' so  $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you again!

Comment: I don't think your second line is correct. If I take for example r=1/2 and x=3.5, then I find f(x)=0.53..., which is not smaller or equal to 1/2.

Comment: @mathastic if $x=3.5$ then $f(x)$ is $0$

Comment: haha ok the same fault, thank you very much